# See costs associated with just one beanstalk environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, billing, cost-management

For AWS is there an easy way to see all the costs associated with just one beanstalk environment? In billing, you can break down the costs by EC instances in locations for example, but if you have multiple beanstalk EC instances running in the same location, this doesn't help too much.

I feel like this would be a pretty common issue, since I'm a single developer but I have multiple projects for different people and at the end of each month I'm trying to find the most accurate way to tell them "hey, here are all the costs associated with your beanstalk instance".

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AWS resources that are part of an Elastic Beanstalk environment are tagged with
`elasticbeanstalk:environment-name` and `elasticbeanstalk:environment-id`. You can set up billing reports based on those tags.  See https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/using-features.tagging.html

Comment: Thank you. I just activated the `elasticbeanstalk:environment-id` and `elasticbeanstalk:environment-name` tags under the cost allocation tags if that is what you mean. Does this mean that in future billing reports these tags will be included near the charges?

Comment: In future cost allocation reports these tags - you only need one of them actually for what you are trying to do - will be included. You can filter the report by a particular value, etc.